# Gstreamer 1.0 saving rtsp stream to file

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

Hi I tried to create pipeline in which I get rtsp stream ,encode it to x264 and save it to mp4 file format but it doesn't seem to work .

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

Comment: There is no element with name `rtsp`, you should use `rtspsrc` element.   Post error output to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry bro that was typo I can start stream and file gets bigger and bigger but when I open it with my player I get error streams can't be read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey I got it:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://ip/url ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4
```

Explanation:
With rtph264depay we extract h264 streams from RTSP then we parse it with h264parse we use mp4 as container and then we save it with filesink

Comment: What does `h264parse` element exactly do?

Comment: It parse raw h264 streams

Comment: What does mean "parse"? What does it do with raw stream?

Comment: Parse means to analyze or separate (input, for example) into more easily processed components.Raw stream is minimally processed .Raw files are named so because they are not yet processed and therefore are not ready to be displayed(in our example).

Comment: @MarvinEffing It's the ending, it needs to be `filesink location=file.mp4` (I've edited the answer)

Comment: perhaps it's a good idea to add a -e to gst-launch so that it crams all the necessary "ending language" down the pipes before closing out due to a Ctrl-C or similar event.