# How to save video stream without using a SDK

Tags: c#, video-streaming, onvif

I'm developing an app that interacts with **ONVIF** compliant network cameras. So far I've been able to manage discovery, security, streaming and ptz by my self according to **ONVIF** specifications. Now I need to save a video stream to a file on my PC, but so far I've been unable to find how to do it without using a third party SDK like *Ozeki* for example.

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the get the list of the profiles configured in the device by using the [media service](http://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media-Service-Spec-v242.pdf) (see §5.2). After that, you need to get the StreamingURI for the desired profile (see 5.15) and then you get the video with RTSP from the URI you obtained.

Comment: I already visualize the video stream using VLC libreries, but what I really need is to storage it on a file in  my PC, for later review.

Comment: Then go with gstreamer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643235/gstreamer-1-0-saving-rtsp-stream-to-file